# sshfs mount won't start from /etc/rc.local

Tags: debian, sshfs, automount

I have the following commands in /etc/rc.local

```
chmod 666 /dev/fuse  
chmod +x /usr/bin/fusermount  
/bin/su someuser -c "/usr/bin/sshfs someuser@someserver:/usr/local/storage /usr/local/storage_remote -o nonempty -o reconnect"
```

If I run them from command line, as root, they work.
If I reboot the server they won't run from /etc/rc.local.
I try to figure out what I do wrong but I don't have console access and I couldn't find any errors in /var/log related to sshfs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what it missed

1. sudo addgroup root fuse
2. sudo addgroup someuser fuse

Also there was an error in /etc/rc.local that prevented the lines with sshfs to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using `fstab` instead to mount filesystems including Fuse based ones. This will stop your box trying to mount network fileststems, for example, if your network is down.

See: http://www.debuntu.org/2006/04/27/39-mounting-a-fuse-filesystem-form-etcfstab

This should be applicable for all Linux distros (excluding package commands)

Comment: Thanks but I would really like the system to try to mount again automatically if a there is a problem.

Comment: @AlexFlo I'm not sure how putting it rc.local will allow it automatically remount.

Comment: its simple, just add "-o reconnect" as in my description above and it will take care to reconnect when the other server is up.

Comment: so add `reconnect` to the options column in fstab. For example: `sshfs#my-remote-user@my-remote-host:/home/my-remote-user /my-local-filesystem/remotefs fuse nonempty,reconnect 0 0`